# What is the meaning of 心理 in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

In this sentence [from an article on 人民网](http://japan.people.com.cn/n1/2017/0927/c35421-29563365.html):

> 收费方面，近距离的心理在15千克以下收入2000日元（约合人民币118元），15-25千克收费2500日元（约合人民币147元）。

However, what is the meaning of 心理 here? It means "psychology", but I don't understand what the "psychology" here mean in this context...

The rough translation would be likely something like the follows (excluding the `近距离的心理`):

> Regarding the price, any baggage under 25kg is 2,000 JPY and 15-25kg is 2,500 JPY.

Comment: some  users feel that 行李 （baggage,luggage) instead of 心理  might make  better sense, 近距离的行李 "short distance luggage" ???

Comment: @user6065 So possibly is it a typo by the author...?

Comment: 心理  might be some kind  of code for
行李

Comment: Typo, don't trust article on Internet. xin li > xing li.

Comment: @Jacob Could you write it as an answer, since you are the first one to point out? I could give you +25 rep then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to many comments here, 心理 is just a typo for 行李. If you replace it with 行李, the sentence makes sense.

> 收费方面，近距离的行李在15千克以下收入2000日元（约合人民币118元），15-25千克收费2500日元（约合人民币147元）。

Answer (score 0):

Very obvious, it is mis typing. The editor is rather neglectful.